# Kind Polymorphic Tuples

Tags: haskell

I noticed with `PolyKinds` and `DataKinds` the following compiles fine:

```
data Pair a b
data Test = Test
type Test2 = Pair 'Test 'Test
```

However:

```
type Test3 = ('Test, 'Test)
```

fails, presumably as `(,)` is not kind polymorphic, which makes sense as it makes values out of it's type arguments and you can't make values of types which are not of kind `*`.

Is there a library that has kind polymorphic tuples (to save me reinventing the wheel)?

I do realise that that unlike real tuples, kind polymorphic tuples will only exist on the type level, but that's all I need for my purposes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are already using `DataKinds`, you should just use the promoted version of built-in tuple *constructor*, as opposed to the type constructor:

```
type Test3 = '( 'Test, 'Test)
```

This has kind `(Test, Test)`.

Note there must be a space between `(` and `'`; `'('Test, 'Test)` is a syntax error (a necessary edge case in the parser).

Comment: Oh that was the issue! That does make sense, '(' will get parsed as a character of course.

Comment: @Clinton, here's a side tip: you will likely find it very useful to define `Fst` and `Snd` type families, and it can be important to use silly-looking constraints like `x ~ '(Fst x, Snd x)`.

Comment: @dfeuer: yep, already made a package for that a few months ago, I'll just update it to include type level tuples:: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/indextype-0.2.0.0